# Python telegram bot cooldown function

Tags: python

I was stuck on my code due to the reason that it's not responding
because i want a bot that /price command has a cooldown and in the next time someone use /price command it will wont respond for 30 mins or prompt people to wait until the cooldown is done so that it will be less spammy on telegram groups when many people doing /price in a same time

```
def price(update, context):

    if chat_data.get('last_time'):
      if datetime.now()-last_time <= my_threshold:

        return

        chat_data['last_time'] = datetime.now()
        update.message.reply_text(
         'Bitcoin PRICE TRACKER \n'
          ' Price: $ ' + usd + '\n'
          ' Marketcap: $ ' + usdcap + '\n'
          ' 24 Hour Volume: $ ' + usdvol + '\n'
          ' 24 Hour Change: % ' + usdchange + '\n'
          '⚙️ Last Updated at:  ' + lastat +'\n'
            )



updater = Updater('mytoken', use_context=True)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('price', price))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something django-rest style, like a decorator?

```py
import datetime

throttle_data = {
    'minutes': 30,
    'last_time': None
}

def throttle(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        delta = now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=throttle_data.get('minutes', 30))
        last_time = throttle_data.get('last_time')
        if not last_time:
            last_time = delta

        if last_time <= delta:
            throttle_data['last_time'] = now
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return not_allowed(*args)
    return wrapper

def not_allowed(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(text="You are not allowed.")

@throttle
def price(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(
         'Bitcoin PRICE TRACKER \n'
          ' Price: $ ' + usd + '\n'
          ' Marketcap: $ ' + usdcap + '\n'
          ' 24 Hour Volume: $ ' + usdvol + '\n'
          ' 24 Hour Change: % ' + usdchange + '\n'
          '⚙️ Last Updated at:  ' + lastat +'\n'
        )



updater = Updater('mytoken', use_context=True)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('price', price))
```

Of course throttle is resetted everytime you restart the bot.
This, by the way, will spam "You are not allowed", so I you have a lot of user throttling, you change `not_allowed` function removing the reply.

Comment: Thanks sir but when i try it and type /price nothing is happening on my bot

Comment: If you copy/pasted, there was a typo. I think now is fixed.

Comment: when delete the throttle the /price works but when i pasted it there's no response

Comment: thanks sir really appreciate it :D
earlier it wont work when i copy pasted it because of my codes above throttle
and now it works fine now thanks