# python telegram bot but need some help on cooldown function for each user in group chat

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61612236/16471684) but it doesn't work for each user, instead it applies the cooldown for all the group members

Comment: all you need to do is to store the `last_time` on a per user basis. To that end, read the users `user_id` from the `update`

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Cron Jobs to do this if you need i will also give code.
by the way **Cron*8 jobs can utilize or you can also use datetime module.
you need to define a a param in add_job.

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone="Asia/Kolkata")
scheduler.add_job(~your func name~, trigger="cron", minute=30)
scheduler.start()
```

also using Datetime module!!
This Is python telgram bot api code

```
jam = time.time()
    new_jam = jam + 10800
    checkchat = get_chat(chat_id, chat_data) #JUST A MODULE TO CHECK CHAT REBULID AS YOU WISH 
    if checkchat.get('status'):
        if jam <= int(checkchat.get('value')):
            timeformatt = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y", time.localtime(checkchat.get('value')))
            update.effective_message.reply_text("You can only use this once a day!\nYou can use again in about `{}`".format(time.formatt), parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
            return
```