# How to add a cooldown time in between commands so that user's can't spam my bot with commands

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Like the title says. I need to make a way to force users to wait maybe 15 or 30 seconds between commands. So if they run it again it will let them know how much longer they need to wait.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python telegram bot but need some help on cooldown function SOLVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61612236/python-telegram-bot-but-need-some-help-on-cooldown-function-solved)

Comment: See [How do I rate limit users of my bot?](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#how-do-i-rate-limit-users-of-my-bot)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by referencing the following code:

```
from time import time

MAX_USAGE = 5


async def callback(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    count = context.user_data.get("usageCount", 0)
    restrict_since = context.user_data.get("restrictSince", 0)

    if restrict_since:
        if (time() - restrict_since) >= 60 * 5: # 5 minutes
            del context.user_data["restrictSince"]
            del context.user_data["usageCount"]
            await update.effective_message.reply_text("I have unrestricted you. Please behave well.")
        else:
            await update.effective_message.reply_text("Back off! Wait for your restriction to expire...")
            raise ApplicationHandlerStop
    else:
        if count == MAX_USAGE:
            context.user_data["restrictSince"] = time()
            await update.effective_message.reply_text("Stop flooding! Don't bother me for 5 minutes...")
            raise ApplicationHandlerStop
        else:
            context.user_data["usageCount"] = count + 1
```